# Google dev console testing without sending apk to production

Tags: android, google-developers-console

Is there any way to Set up my application for beta testing without sending it to production?

I set up the app on the Dev console,it's the first version, and want to test it with a few individuals. I picked Alpha testing, uploaded the APK and supplied their gmail accounts but still haven't received the emails, which were 10+ hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case somebody comes across this. You cannot put an APK up for Testers until you 'Publish' the app. This means putting in all the screenshots, doing the ratings... etc. It should be noted it doesn't put the App on the store.

Answer (score 0):

Have any of your testers tried the opt-in URL?  Should be something like https://play.google.com/apps/testing/{package-name}.

Comment: It says "An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app."

Comment: Did you ever try going to https://play.google.com/apps/testing/your-package-name?